# Some Documents are missing in SharePoint 2013 search results

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I am facing an issue in my search service application that some documents are missing from the crawling results. I am using SharePoint 2013 out of the box search result web part for displaying search results.

As a solution, I have tried by resetting index about 3 to 4 times, and also by creating the new search service application, but no luck at all. The documents are still missing from search.

I have checked the permissions on the document libraries and site also, but permission is not an issue.

There are no crawling rules in my service application. The only one thing is I have started continuous crawl in my service application.

I am also using one search refiner web part. Refinement options are also not showing for the missing documents, **(However , when we edit web part and click on preview refiners option, it is showing the missing documents. But after saving that web part properties the results are not showing. )**

Please help my giving some hint on how can i fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After spending couple of days on this issue,  I came to know that issue was related to managed metadata columns that were bind through code. I just open document library and iterate each items and updated items again by using power shell script using just item.Update(). And that's worked !! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have observed exactly the same issue that few results are not displayed as they are considered as "duplicates". I added a content editor web part with following script to get the results back (as given in this article - http://www.eliostruyf.com/view-duplicate-results-sharepoint-2013-search-center-via-javascript/ ).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Show duplicated results

if (typeof Srch.U.fillKeywordQuery !== 'undefined') 
{
    var originalFillKeywordQuery = Srch.U.fillKeywordQuery;
    Srch.U.fillKeywordQuery = function(query, dp) 
    dp.set_trimDuplicates(false);  
    originalFillKeywordQuery(query, dp);
};
}
```